# Text file comparisons

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I need to compare data from two files.
files is as follow:

**users.txt**

```
admin, adm1n
jurie, jur5
```

**tasks.txt**

```
admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and 
passwords for all team members that will be using this program., 10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No
admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate 
tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No
jurie, meeting, arrange monthly management meeting, 20 July 2021, 30 Jul 2021, Yes
```

Now I need to know how to compare the two files to show for users listed how many lines has `'No'`.

What the calculation must look like is:

```
admin : 2
jurie : 0
```

but I do not know how to write the code to count the No statements.
At this time my code is as follow:

```
tasks_issued = {}
with open('user.txt', 'r') as user_file, open('tasks.txt', 'r') as task_file:
    words = user_file.read().split()
    del words[1::2]
    tasks_issued = {i:0 for i in words}
    for line in task_file:
        line_split = line.split()
        for word in line_split:
          if word in tasks_issued: 
            tasks_issued[word] += 1
```

but this only compares the words that are the same.
I did try:

```
with open('user.txt', 'r') as user_file, open('tasks.txt', 'r') as task_file:
   words = user_file.read().split()
   del words[1::2]
   tasks_open = {i:0 for i in words}
   for line in task_file:
       line_split = line.split()
       if line_split == "No":
          for word in line_split:
             if word in tasks_open:
                tasks_open[word] += 1
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Check the documentation of `split()`. It returns a list. So `line_split` will be of type list. You then try to do `if line_split == "No"` which will ***always*** be `False` no matter the content. Did you mean `if "No" in line_split`?

Comment: Also note that doing `if word in tasks_open` will not help you because the names have a `,` after them. So maybe do `line_split = line.split(', ')`

Comment: You don't need to split the line at all. Just do `if "No" in line: for name in tasks_open: if name in line: tasks_open[name] += 1`

Comment: Careful, `if "No" in line_split` is extremely brittle and likely not really what you want.

Comment: So maybe `if line_split[-1] == "No"` for that matter...